# Gerrit REST API: cannot use _sortkey to resume a query

Tags: json, rest, gerrit

I'm using [Gerrit REST API](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html) to query all changes whose status is "merged". My query is

```
https://android-review.googlesource.com/changes/?q=status:merged&n=2
```

where "n=2" limits the size of query results to 2. So I got a JSON object like:

[image]

Of course there are more results. According to the REST document:

> If the n query parameter is supplied and additional changes exist that match the query beyond the end, the last change object has a _more_changes: true JSON field set. Callers can resume a query with the N query parameter, supplying the last change’s _sortkey field as the value.

So I add the query parameter N with the _sortkey of the last change 100309. The new query is:

```
https://android-review.googlesource.com/changes/?q=status:merged&n=2&N=002e4203000187d5
```

With this new query, I was hoping that I'll get another 2 new query results, since I provided the _sortkey as a cursor of my previous search results.

However, **it's really weird that this new query returns exactly the same results as the previous query, instead of the next 2 results as I expected**. It seems like providing "N=002e4203000187d5" has no effect at all.

Does anybody know why using _sortkey to resume my query doesn't work?

Comment: Which version of Gerrit are you using?  I just checked a script I use and it follows that exact syntax but works fine.  I'm hitting a server running 2.8.3.

Comment: @Brad I query the Android Gerrit (https://android-review.googlesource.com/) but not sure which version of Gerrit it uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I chatted with one of the developers at Google, and he confirmed that _sortkey has been removed from the newer versions of Gerrit they are running at android-review and gerrit-review.  The N= parameter is no longer valid.  The documentation will be updated to reflect this.

The alternative is to use &S=x to skip x results, which I tested and works well.

Comment: The documentation hasn't been updated at this point, therefore I'm really confused. Thank you very much for the information.

Answer (score 1):

**sortkey** is deprecated in Gerrit v2.9 -
see the [(Gerrit) ReleaseNotes-2.9.txt](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit/+/master/ReleaseNotes/ReleaseNotes-2.9.txt), under ***REST API - Changes***:

> [[sortkey-deprecation]]
>
> - Results returned by the [[query changes](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.9/rest-api-changes.html#list-changes)] endpoint are now paginated using offsets instead of sortkeys.
>
>   - The `sortkey` and `sortkey_prev` parameters on the endpoint are deprecated.
>       The results are now paginated using the `--limit` (`-n`) option to limit the number of results, and the `-S` option to set the start point.
>   - Queries with sortkeys are still supported against old index versions, to enable online reindexing while clients have an older JS version.

See also here -
[*PSA: Removing the "sortkey" field from the gerrit-on-borg query interface*](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-os-dev/tohd-MPmdTI):

> ...
>   Our solution is to kill the sortkey field and its related search operators (sortkey_before, sortkey_after, and resume_sortkey).
>
> There are two ways you can achieve similar functionality.
>
> 1. Add "&S=" to your query to skip a fixed number of results.
>      (Note that this redoes the search so new results may have jumped ahead and
>      you might process the same change twice.
>      This is true of the resume_sortkey implementation as well,
>      so your code should already be able to handle this.)
> 2. Use the before/after operators.
>      Instead of taking the sortkey field from the last returned change and
>      using it in a resume_sortkey operator, you take the updated field from
>      the last returned change and use it in a before operator.
>      (This has slightly different semantics than the sortkey field, which
>      uses the change number as a tiebreaker when changes have similar updated times.)
>
> ...